# How to stop a running method with keyboard input in a Console Application on C#?

Tags: c#, input, while-loop, user-input, break

In short, I'm utilizing C# to scientific computation and I've written a method that has a while loop that may run to a user-specified quantity of steps... Actually, this method may take too long to execute (like more than 5 hours). When it takes this long, I may want to stop the method pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, for example.

As I read something about breaking `while`, it is as simple as a `Boolean` flag or something like this. So I thought in something like this:

```
public Double? Run(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < n) && (/* inputkey != ConsoleKey.Escape */))
    {
        // here goes the heavy computation thing
        // and I need to read some "inputkey" as well to break this loop
        i++;
    }
    // I'm not worried about the return statement, as it is easy to do...
    // returns null if the user skipped the method by pressing Escape
    // returns null if the method didn't converged
    // returns the double value that the method calculated otherwise
}
```

Well, this is what I wondered until now... So please, could you give useful ideas to this extent? How can I wait for a user input (I thought about `Events`, but I'm not sure how to implement it here and I think that it will make the code even slower, if I have to listen to a key at every while step the code goes into...

Well, any ideas or comments?

---

**Update**: I think I should have had described better the problem. All the solutions you gave me may solve this problem I proposed, but I think I was not completely reliable to my real problem. I don't know if I should ask another question or keep with this one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could run this method from a separate thread and set a stop variable when a key is pressed:

```
object myLock = new object();
bool stopProcessing = false;

public Double? Run(int n)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        lock(myLock)
        {
            if(stopProcessing)
                break;
        }
        // here goes the heavy computation thing
        // and I need to read some "inputkey" as well to break this loop
        i++;
    }
}
```

and when a key is pressed, update stopProcessing accordingly:

```
Console.ReadKey();
lock(myLock)
{
    stopProcessing = true;
}
```

Comment: I think your idea is more or less Jeff's Idea isn't it? Thanks for both!

Answer (score 5):

If you're just wanting to stop the application, Ctrl-C from the command line will do it.  If you really need to intercept input during a long running process, you might want to spawn a worker thread to do the long running process and then just use the main thread to interact with the console (i.e. Console.ReadLine()).

Comment: I agree, take a look at the BackgroundWorker: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: Agreed.  Background Worker is the best way to do this.  You may even be able to spawn multiple threads so your "long running process" can be a bit less long running.

Comment: Well, I've already used BackgroundWorker for a GUI app I builded, but I didn't know I could use it in Console apps as well. Now, regarding your first point, I can't use only CTRL C, as this was just a simple example of what I have... Actually I run the `Run()` method dozens of times and perform an average with the returned values, and I do this for various sets of parameters, intending to write a file in the end of the program... My point is, if I press CTRL C, the programs stops definitely, not only skips a value... You see? Thanks for the tip of the bg worker!

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do this using threading. When you start the task, spawn a new thread and execute the task on that thread. Then in your Program.cs, wait for user input. If the user enters something meaningful - in your case, the `Esc` key - alert the background thread of the action. The simplest way to do this is by setting a static variable. The background thread will be checking this static variable and when it has been changed, the background thread will clean itself up and abort.

See the [MSDN article on Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e8s7xdd%28VS.71%29.aspx).

A code sample will be a little more in depth, but it would look something like this:

```
public class Program.cs
{
    public static myFlag = false;
    public void Main()
    {
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
        thread.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
        myFlag = true;
    }
    public static DoWork()
    {
        while(myFlag == false)
        {
            DoMoreWork();
        }
        CleanUp()
    }
    public static DoMoreWork() { }
    public static CleanUp() { }

}
```

Comment: I think your idea is more or less Mark's Idea isn't it? Thanks for both!

Comment: @Jeff: be careful though; this is not thread-safe without locking (you will encounter a race condition).

Comment: @Girardi yes, we suggested pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @Mark you're right. i was just trying to provide a sample for Girardi to go with and I wasnt planing on mocking up the whole 9 yards. also, situation sounds pretty simple with a limited audience so the race condition is probably an edge case. still, locking is definitely the right way to go.

Comment: @Jeff: I just wanted to point it out; I have actually had a post of mine deleted before because I was not fully thread-safe with an example, so I have learned to be explicit :-)

Comment: @Mark wow! there's gotta be a middle ground between providing help and fully developing an idea for someone. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

pool on Console.KeyAvailable in timely manner and take the action accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool _cancelled = false;
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var computationTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(PerformIncredibleComputation);
            var acceptCancelKey = Task.Factory.StartNew(AcceptCancel);


        while (!acceptCancelKey.IsCompleted && ! computationTask.IsCompleted)
        {

            computationTask.Wait (100);        
        }

        if( acceptCancelKey.IsCompleted && !computationTask.IsCompleted )
        {
            computationTask.Wait (new System.Threading.CancellationToken ());
        }
        else if(!acceptCancelKey.IsCompleted)
        {
            acceptCancelKey.Wait(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
        }


    }


    private static void PerformIncredibleComputation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Performing computation.");
        int ticks = Environment.TickCount;
        int diff = Environment.TickCount - ticks;
        while (!_cancelled && diff < 10000)
        {
           //computing  
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Computation finished");
    }

    private static void AcceptCancel()
    {

        var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to cancel");
        while(key.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
        _cancelled = true;
        Console.Write("Computation was cancelled");

    }
}
```

}